# Visualizar valores adicionandos no object FormData e remover

Tags: javascript, formdata

Muitas vezes tentei debugar uma instância do objeto `FormData`, porém não consigo ver os valores armazenados pelo método `append`.

Tentei isso:

```
f = new FormData();

f.append('name', 'Wallace Maxters');

f.append('image', $('#file').prop('files')[0]);

// tento obter o conteúdo adicionando

f.toString() //"[object FormData]"

console.log(f['name']) // undefined
```

Como posso visualizar os valores que armazenei dentro de uma instância do objeto `FormData`? Há alguma maneira de se fazer isso?

Como faria pra remover o valor "name" adicionando no objeto do exemplo acima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `formData` não permite retirar informação depois dela ter sido inserida.

Se quiseres ter a certeza que tens o conteúdo certo tens de fazer um objeto à parte e depois converter em formData.

Há algumas respostas no SOen <sup>([esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17067016/2256325) ou [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21443721/2256325))</sup> sobre isto e curiosamente a especificação da W3C aponta para [novas funcionalidades no futuro](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-formdata)... para além do `.append()` haverá `has`, `delete`, `get`, `getAll` e `set`. Vamos ver quando será implementado.